# Travel from a point A to all remaining points via nearest neighbor point first

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, point, nearest-neighbor

I have multiple points represented in the picture. The distance between two nearest points vertically (between `A` and `B`, or `B` and `C`, or `D` and `E` etc.) is `distance_y`. The distance between two nearest points horizontally (between `A` and `D`, etc.) is `distance_x`.

Suppose that:

`distance_y < distance_x < 2*distance_y`

```
                distance_x
           A <-------------> D <-------------> G
           | 
distance_y |
           | 
           B <-------------> E <-------------> H

           -

           C <-------------> F <-------------> I
```

I formulate the distance between two any points as follows:

```
Distance(point P1, point P2) = m * distance_x + n * distance_y
```

For example, for the point `A` and `B`, `m = 0` and `n = 1;`

The question is: from a point `P`, how can I run through all the remaining points via the nearest neighbors first (i.e in descending order of distance far from point `P`)?

I don't want to calculate the entire distance from other points to `P` and then sort these points in descending order of distance from `P` because it's time-consuming. I want to search for the algorithm which can evaluate the position of the neighbor rapidly without calculating the position of further points.

For example, from point `D`, the following points will be

```
E (m= 0, n = 1),
A (m= 1, n = 0),
G (m= 1, n = 0),
F (m =0, n = 2),
B (m= 1, n = 1),
H (m= 1, n = 1),
C (m= 1, n = 2),
I (m= 1, n = 2).
```

How can I determine the order of `m` and `n` for searching the nearest neighbors?

Comment: Just to be sure: all nodes are connected via all possible vertical and horizontal lines? i.e. in your case there is a connection H - I for example?

Comment: Yes, each node has a vertical neighbor and horizontal neighbor. thus, there is a connection H-I

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood, but looks like a Dijkstra algoruthm application:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm

Comment: He stated that he does not want to calculate all distances, so I assume he knows about Dijkstras Algorithm and chooses not to use it

Answer (score 0):

You have only 2 kinds of connections: long and short.

Store your graph as an adjacency list where each node has 2 containers, rather a list of nodes. First container has all the short (`y`) distance nodes, while the second long (`x`) distance nodes.

Perform a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) search on the graph, the only difference is that you will have two search queues.

From the starting node: you add short distance container to first queue and long distance to second queue. You pop the container from first queue and go through its elements and group all short distance containers of each node into one and add them the to first queue and long distance (also all grouped together) to second one, then you pop a container from your second queue and for every node in that container you go adding short distance containers together into a big one and then the big one to second queue and long distance to first one. Then you pop again a container from the first queue...

To sum up: you pop one by one each queue. The result is a container with nodes, you go through each node and gather all the short distance containers and add those to the queue you have popped a container from, the same thing happens with the long distance containers only that they are added to the first queue.

The only thing is that with this algorithm `n` long is always better then `n+1`short.

This is how the traversal will look like starting from C, the bumber next to each node shows the order they are reached.

```
A5---B2---C0---D2---E5 
|    |    |    |    |
F8---G4---H1---I4---L8
|    |    |    |    |
M10--N7---O3---R7---P10
|    |    |    |    |
W11--Y9---X6---T9---S11
```

Comment: it's very interesting your answer. Can you show me a short pseudocode for this, it may be more clear for me? Anyway, the assumption that I made: distance_y < distance_x < 2*distance_y is just a example.        I look for a general case (may be distance_x = distance_y or distance_x < 3*distance_y, etc.)

Comment: @Bryan in this case the code will not work. The problem is that the code depends on the ratio of long and short distance, because if again you think of it as the BFS it basically should just jump from one level of nodes to another depending on the ratio. If as you say the ratio may vary I think you should better perform the shortest path algorithm like Dijkstras and sort the nodes. Since sorting is ´O(nlgn)` the complexity of Dijkstras will be dominant i.e. `O(k+nlgn)` which is not that bad.

Comment: Do you mean that your code works for every cases that the ratio of long and short distance is fixed and knew in advance? Let's say distance_y = 20 and distance_x = 25? I don't understand why  3 * distance_y > 2 * distance_x as you mentioned in your first answer.

Comment: More exactly the program will consider always will consider `n` long better then `n+1` short, so yes I have to change that statement in the answer.